# Wordpress: How to recreate wpdb connection after $wpdb->close()

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am making a script which insert more than 10K products to Woocommerce via API. I wrote full script and it is working properly untill 5600 products inserted and after that script just stop. No error.

So I am thinking it is Db connection or some db restriction which dont allow me to use more Db object.So I thought to close DB connection by using $wpdb->close() after loop number 5500 and then try to renew it inside foreach loop of products, It is running till 5500 but at 5501 it gives error.

So can anyone pls help me that after wpdb->close how I can start again wpdb connection?

**Edit 1**: Below is example of code So you can understand what I am trying to achieve.

```
foreach($products as $prod){ // Loop will run for more than 10K
  // Here I am inserting woocommerce products and info of products
  // for example inserting terms for Brands taxonomy
  
   global $wpdb;


  // Somewhere here I am using code to insert term for Brand Taxonomy
  // But my loop stopped at wp_insert_term below giving error :
  // Could not insert term into the database.

   if(!term_exists($prod->brand, 'pwb-brand')){
        $term = wp_insert_term($prod->brand, 'pwb-brand');
        $term_taxonomy_brand_ids = wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, array( $term['term_id'] ), 'pwb-brand' );
   } else {   
        $term_b = get_term_by( 'name', $prod->fabricante, 'pwb-brand' );
        $term_taxonomy_brand_ids = wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, array( $term_b->term_id ), 'pwb-brand' );
   }
   if($cnt == 5500){
      $wpdb->close();
      $wpdb = new wpdb(DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST);
    }

   $cnt++;
}
```

**Edit 2**: As @LoicTheAztec suggested [`WPDB method flush()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/#clearing-the-cache) , I tried and after using flush, foreach loop continue inserting next records but still same issue after 5600 records script just stop. No error.

Comment: Did you tried clearing the cache using the [`WPDB` method `flush()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/#clearing-the-cache) instead of closing the connexion with `close()` method.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thanks for suggesting `flush()` method. I tried it and Yes after using flush foreach loop continue inserting next records but still same issue after 5600 records script just stop. No error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to close the connection with the below code

```
$wpdb->close()
```

and To recreate the connection try the below code

```
$wpdb = new wpdb( "user", "password", "dbname", "localhost" );
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I am sorry I should have added example of code before. Anyway I edited my question and added code and you can see I already tried same thing you asked me to do but next time loop runs it give me error while using wp_insert_term